# Changing the network name of a Brother printer

Tags: printer, network-printer, brother-printer

At work we have two MFC-9330CDW printers that are connected to the LAN. Windows shows these printers in Explorer under the same name, the only difference being the (what I assume is) serial number in brackets:

[image: Screenshot of two network printers]

While we can connect to these printers with ease, I cannot figure out a way in the admin panel to change these two network names. It confuses users because these are also the names used in applications when selecting a printer. I'd rather see the node names appear here instead of the serial, simply because it's unclear to a lot of users which printer is which. (they're physically on opposite sides of the office)

Is there any way to change this name?

I am aware that Brother's own tool "BRAdmin" allows for quick network scanning and reports the printers using their node names but this doesn't change the network name. I am also aware that I can change the name of the printer *locally* but having to do that every time we get a new computer is a real pain - especially because I myself forget which printer is which.

For clarification, I am a sysadmin, and I'm allowed to make these changes.

Comment: Usually such printers have a web GUI running on port 80 that allows to configure a lot of stuff. AFAIK also the printer name.

Comment: @Robert Correct, they have a GUI, but I can only seem to adjust the NetBIOS name and Node name. I've adjusted both but they don't reflect on the names used by Windows.

Comment: Are your computers configured to directly print over IP to the printer? Because usually a printer server is used and there you could define the printer names once and make them valid for every other computer.

Comment: We add the printers to Windows by simply clicking "Add a printer or scanner" in Settings, so I'm guessing direct print over IP. We don't have a printer server in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the printers' webpages, go to

- the Network tab
- Protocol menu
- select the Advanced Settings for the Web Services Protocol
- change the Web Services Name & click Submit
- back to the Protocol page
- same for Air Drop if desired
- click submit at the bottom of the Protocol page

Comment: At the end adding the printer to windows would have display the original name!!!

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with air print, two brother printers, even though they were different, users wouldn’t be able to tell them apart just from model number.  I got the ip address of each and logged in using the default password for each printer.  Click the network tab then protocol tab and then air print.  That was where I could change how an iPhone would see the printer,  I called one brother color and the other brother black and white.  Maybe there is something in those settings that would help you also.